# Process duplicate rows in result set but leave one unprocessed

Tags: vb.net, db2

I am writing a script in VB.NET that uses a result set with 7 columns and duplicate rows.  Six of the seven columns are identical.  The first column is an identity number, and the fifth column is numbered sequentially, based on how many duplicate rows there are for the identity number.  Some identity numbers have three duplicates and some have as many as 8 - 10 duplicates.

I need to loop through the result set in VB.NET and **process** ***only the duplicate rows***, leaving one row for each identity number unprocessed.  I don't want to delete the duplicate rows in the result set, I just want to process them in my script and leave one unprocessed row behind.

Please recommend solution options.

Thanks.

Comment: `Please recommend solution options` SO is for *answers*  As is, this non question doesnt give us a starting point - please show the code you are using to get the data into your app

Comment: I cannot show the code because I work for a government agency and the query contains Personally Identifiable Information.  I'm working from a pretty big query with several subqueries to update old vb6 script to vb.net.

Comment: So process every row where your duplicate counter number is greater 1 :-) What is your question? Be more precise please.

Comment: They are all greater than one.  I have a list of identity numbers (not in the sense of an identity column) and a sequential task number in a result set.  Every identity number has three or more task numbers associated with it.  I'm going between bringing in a data table and running a function to process that table row by row, but right now I don't have a way to distinguish between the duplicate rows so that I can process all but one for each identity number.

Comment: `For n As Int32 = 1 To SecretDataTable.Rows.Count-1`  since the first element will be Rows(0), you skipped the first one and can "process" all the rest

Comment: If doing this with a SQL SELECT statement is an option I can post an example that will select duplicates that excludes the primary key. The example is for SQL-Server but should work fine with DB2. The example is current on MSDN Code samples website and can provide a link if requested.

Answer (score 0):

I made no changes to the result set.  In the VB.NET code, outside the For Each Row loop, I created a string variable set to empty.  Inside the loop, I compared the string variable with the identity value for each row.  The first row doesn't match, of course, so the process doesn't run. I then assign the string variable the identity value for that row.  On the second pass, the string variable does match the identity value from the second row, so the process runs for that row and all the subsequent duplicate rows.  When a new identity comes up, it does not match the string variable and so the process does not run for that row, thus preserving one copy of that identity value and processing all the duplicates.  I suppose this could have been done in SQL, but we got it to work in code.